# Is it possible to create a MYSQL query based on all "unknown" $_GET parameters of the url?

Tags: php, sql, get

I know for example if you KNOW what parameters to expect you can simply use

```
$_GET['parameter']
```

in your MYSQL query. What if you expect 4-5 parameters, however maybe NOT all of them are passed? For example, let's say the user wants to list all the products which have a `price` more than `20$` and a `warranty` of `2` years.

The user could have more search options like for example, the product category should be `2` which is for `Laptops`

now, my question is, should I have many if statements and check for each possible parameter to see if they are set, and if they are then include them in my MYSQL query, or is there a faster way?
thanks in advance

Comment: I would not allow the URL parameter to determine what happens in your database, Might be more work but it's much safer to handle all the options yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try foreach. Something like:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
   switch($key) {
      case "category":
         $str[] = "category = '". mysql_real_escape_string($value) ."'";
         break;
      case "price":
         $str[] = "price > '". mysql_real_escape_string($value) ."'";
         break;
      case "warranty":
         $str[] = "warranty > '". mysql_real_escape_string($value) ."'";
         break;
   }
}
//create the mysql string with
$str_where = "WHERE " . implode('AND', $str);
```

you can uset he str_where string to filter the products.

Comment: -1 for the gaping sql injection hole. You also forgot spaces around the `'AND'`

Comment: Eeek. Please look up SQL injection, input filtering and output escaping.

Comment: I fixed the mysql injection. I use good frameworks that prevent this by default.

Comment: is mysql_real_escape_string enough for SQL injections? I've heard people preferring PDO to avoid them. I'm new to PHP and I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: you should always use pdo, i am just too tired now to create everything.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons I would definitely list the available keys with their datatypes that can be used in the query first.

```
$keys = array(
    'category'  => PDO::PARAM_INT,
    'price'     => PDO::PARAM_INT,
    'etc'       => PDO::PARAM_STR
);
// all the available keys for the query and their types

$queryStr = "SELECT * FROM `some_table` WHERE `yourCond`='someVal'";
// initial query you have

$userVals = array();
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $k = strtolower($key);
    if (!in_array($k,array_keys($keys)) || empty($value))
    // if the key is not listed in the keys array
    // or the value is empty we skip it
        continue;
    $queryStr .= " AND `$k` = :{$k} ";
    // modify query
    $userVals[$k] = $value;
    // and add the key-value pair into user values array
}

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=someHost;dbname=someDB','someUsername','somePassword');
// create DB connection
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
// enable error reporting
$stmt = $db->prepare($queryStr);
// prepare query string
foreach ($userVals as $k => $v) {
    $stmt->bindParam(":{$k}",$v,$keys[$k]);
    // bind each parameter with the right datatype
}

$stmt->execute();
// and execute the query
```